# Automatic newlines and formatting for blogging software

Tags: php, newline, blogs

I'm writing by own blogging engine in PHP with a MYSQL backend database. MY question is: How would you go about making user comments and blog posts include newlines wherever they are appropriate?

For example, if a user hits the return key in the message/comments box how would this translate into a new line that would show in the browser when the comment is viewed?

Answer (score 7):

PHP has a function: nl2br which turns new lines into `<br />`

[www.php.net/nl2br](https://www.php.net/nl2br)

Comment: I learnt not to trust functions like that after the PHP developers changed the semantics in a minor patch version for no reason.

Comment: Do you have specifics?  I see this function changed at 5.3.0 to add a "is xhtml" bool parameter and at 4.0.5 it was made XHMTL compliant by adding a closing slash to the tag.  Or is there a specific function you're referring to?

Comment: I'm talking about the 4.0.5 change. It was totally unnecessary, entirely inappropriate for a minor patch version, and broke code. What were they thinking?  It's that kind of cowboy attitude that makes me glad I don't have to write PHP any more.

Comment: Well... 4.0.5 was a long time ago. They seem (to me) to have a much more reasoned development process now. Typically if they do something like that now they add an option to enable it (hence the is xhtml parameter).

Comment: 4.0.5 is a long time ago, but there is other stuff just like that. I get all the issues people have just keep in mind that PHP is a community product. Report bugs, post to mailinglists. You have the power! (I know it sounds like a commercial, but it's really true.)

Comment: I can think of quite a few things about the development process, such as the lack of addressing needle haystack/haystack needle ordering while making major revisions.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `\n\n` with `</p><p>` and then replace `\n` with `<br>`.

PS: Pirate day was last week :).

Comment: If you do this, make sure to wrap the entire output with <p> and </p>!

Comment: Doesn't this suggestion assume that you always preface content with <p>?

Comment: Yes, but given that he's talking about user comments and blog posts, that's not an unreasonable assumption.

Answer (score 1):

nl2br() (http://php.net/nl2br) is perfectly good, however that Wordpress Guy (Matt Mullenweg) has a really good function, which is a bit more advanced as it converts double line breaks to paragraphs instead (better semantically). You can find it in the Wordpress source code or here: http://ma.tt/scripts/autop/

Answer (score 0):

It's also important what your using for a comment editor.  If your using a standard textbox then yes, nl2br is what your looking for.  If your going a bit more advanced such as using a WYSIWYG editor like tinyMCE, then it has configuration that can handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to need more formatting options (beyond paragraphs), employ something like [Text_Wiki](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki) or [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).

The advantages would be:

- no need to allow HTML and deal with all the filtering (that's good :-))
- clear/familiar guide to formatting data
- a lot of flexibility when you generate the HTML (in the end for display)

The disadvantages:

- no HTML (blessing and curse ;-))
- people might not be familiar the syntax